# Twitter API: Get latest nearby tweets

Tags: geolocation, twitter

I see the request API docs here: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets
I understand that there's a geocode field. The problem is that the query field is required meaning I have to search something that's related in that area. Is it possible to just get ALL the latest tweets around that area without specifying a query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is deliberate to prevent huge demand on the servers, you need to specify something else. My tip - use the date/time related query fields. This is acceptable, and if you really need "forever", you can make more requests.